# База данных в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Кто может, - дайте, пож. ссылку на внятную инф. по работе PhpStorm с базой данных MySQL.
Благодарю.

Comment: туториал самого phpstorm не подходит? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Databases+and+SQL+Editor+in+PhpStorm

Comment: Очень Вам благодарен (иногда надо чтобы носом кто-то ткнул ))).
Туториал просто шикарный!!